# making a legend in Line graph with a grouping variable, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have data that looks like this, where line is a grouping variable representing a genetic line, `tp` is a time point (x axis), `expr` is gene expression relative to 0 tine point, and `col` is a color assignment for each line:

```
line    tp    expr           col
358 LL  0   0                yellowgreen
358 LL  30  -2.459476064     yellowgreen
358 LL  60  0.645900697      yellowgreen
358 LL  90  0.040513329      yellowgreen
380 LL  0   0                indianred4
380 LL  30  0.893111431      indianred4
380 LL  60  0.847461181      indianred4
380 LL  90  -0.867875889     indianred4
441 HL  0   0                blue
441 HL  30  1.934555631      blue
441 HL  60  3.144618461      blue
441 HL  90  1.883829994      blue
486 LL  0   0                bisque4
487 LL  30  -0.064427095     bisque4
488 LL  60  0.015498302      bisque4
489 LL  90  1.047567166      bisque4
832 HL  0   0                blueviolet
832 HL  30  -0.233381601     blueviolet
832 HL  60  -3.562884526     blueviolet
832 HL  90  -0.038818998     blueviolet
913 HL  0   0                orange
913 HL  30  0.799850689      orange
913 HL  60  0.818883617      orange
913 HL  90  -0.07758268      orange
Average 0   0                black
Average 30  0.145038832      black
Average 60  0.318246289      black
Average 90  0.331272154      black
```

using the following code, I produce exactly what I want but with no legend:

```
# Set color spectrums:
larvae_col <- as.vector(CG13288_L$col)

ggplot(data=CG13288_L, aes(x = tp, y = expr, group=line)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, color=larvae_col) + 
  theme_light() + theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  labs(title="CG13288 (FBgn0035648) - Larvae", x="Time Point", y="LogFC Expression") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", face="bold", size=35, margin=margin(20,0,0,0))) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", face="bold", size=35, margin=margin(0,20,0,0))) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(color="black", face="bold", size=40, margin=margin(0,0,20,0))) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=30, color="black", face="bold")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", size=1.5)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size=1.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.01,0.04)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-4,4), breaks=c(-4,-2,0,2,4), expand=c(0.02,0.01))

ggsave("CG13288_L.pdf", plot = last_plot(), device = "pdf", width = 15, height = 10, units = "in", useDingbats=FALSE)
```

I have toyed around with using "color" instead of "group" on the first line but get vertical lines for each `tp` (time point). How can I add a legend to this?

Comment: Do you really want `486 LL`, `487 LL`, etc. to all be `bisque4`? Should these maybe be grouped together instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a variable to automatically appear in legends, you should specify it within the aes object.
Just change your line 2 to:

```
geom_line(size=1, aes(colour=col)) +
```

This way your legend would assign the color names to ggplot default colors. To change the default ggplot colors, you can add:

```
scale_colour_manual(values=unique(larvae_col))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Now, how do I change what appears in the legend?

Comment: I assume you want the legend labels to be your **tp** column and legend colors to be your **col** column. This should work: geom_line(size=1, aes(colour=tp)) + scale_colour_manual(values=unique(larvae_col))

Comment: So i want to color by line so I changed aes(colour=tp)) to aes(colour=line)).

But I got the following error: Error: Don't know how to add RHS to a theme object

Comment: If I run ggplot(data=CG13288_L, aes(x = tp, y = expr, group=line)) + 
  geom_line(size=1, aes(color=line)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=unique(larvae_col))

I get another error now: Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 10 needed but only 7 provided.

it's creating lines 487, 488, and 489 even though they do not exist

Comment: Nevermind! It worked. There was an issue with the input file. SOLVED!